# Use 3D Texture for Fragment shader on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I need to use 3D Texture in my fragment shader on Android, but get compiling error.
I use GLES3.0 and I think it should support 3D texture.
My shader looks as follows:

```c
#extension GL_OES_texture_3D : enable

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler3D u_Texture;
```

Without `#extension GL_OES_texture_3D : enable` I got error

> L0003: Keyword 'sampler3D' is reserved

With `#extension GL_OES_texture_3D : enable`, I got error

> S0032: no default precision defined for variable 'u_Texture'

Even I use `uniform medium float sampler3D u_Texture`, I got

> Expect, found sampler3D
>   error.

Hope get your help!

Many thanks.

YL

Comment: https://github.com/google/grafika
This is basic Android OpenGL ES example project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you've to specify the glsl version by a version qualifier in the first line of the shader program:

```c
#version 300 es
```

The precision qualifier is either `highp`, `mediump` or `lowp` and has to be specified before the type. The type is `sampler3D` rather than `float`.

The declaration

> ```c
> uniform medium float sampler3D u_Texture
> ```

has 2 types (`float` and `sampler3D`), so it causes a syntax error.

It has to be

```c
#version 300 es

uniform medium sampler3D u_Texture;
```

or by the use of a default precision qualifier

```c
#version 300 es
precision mediump sampler3D;

uniform sampler3D u_Texture;
```

(Of course `precision mediump float;` has to be specified, too)

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.20 Specification - 4.7.3. Precision Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.html#precision-and-precision-qualifiers)

Comment: You should not need the `#extension` line here; 3D textures are core functionality in ES 3.0. I'd guess the OP was missing `#version 300 es`.